# How to import Firefox code modules with WebExtensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to write a WebExtensions add-on for Firefox and would really like to utilize the [*Services.jsm* code module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm).

How can I use Services.jsm with WebExtensions? I can use it in Add-on SDK and legacy add-ons, but I can't find documentation on how to do it in WebExtensions.

Is there something I am missing here, or do I need to forget about *Services.jsm* (and all of the other Firefox code modules for that matter) and try to find something comparable under the WebExtensions hierarchy?

Comment: Thanks! I made it more general about importing code modules in general. I would like to see if there is maybe some work around that allows me to use exterior modules

Comment: There is a *vast* difference between a question asking to use external modules (i.e. code modules which you include with your add-on or code from the network) and asking to use the Firefox code modules that are for the Add-on SDK and/or legacy add-ons. If you are really asking about both, then doing so in a single question is too broad. Such a question will probably be be closed. You need to pick one or the other per question (feel free to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about the one which you don't want to include in this question.

Comment: Frankly, even asking, generically, how to use external modules is too broad. You would need to add details about what you are wanting to do (e.g. code included with your extension (e.g. your own modules, libraries downloaded and included in your extension)? code loaded dynamically from the network?  in a background script?,  a content script? a popup?, etc.) Are you using some framework intended to facilitate doing exactly that?

Comment: Are you asking only about importing the JavaScript code modules that are part of Firefox (i.e. available through a `resources://` URL), or are you asking about JavaScript code modules in general (i.e. any code anywhere which is organized in a separate file, or specifically as a code module)?

Comment: Yes Firefox code modules.

Comment: OK, then the proposed duplicate is accurate. The same answer applies for all of the Firefox JavaScript code modules which Add-on SDK and legacy extensions would access through `resource://` URLs. To paraphrase the proposed duplicate: No, it is not possible to use those in WebExtensions add-ons. For WebExtension add-ons, you should forget about all of those Firefox code modules, and only use the [APIs provided by WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API), standard Web APIs, or normal JavaScript libraries you specifically include in your extension.